# How can I get the address of self?

Tags: cython

How can I do this:

```py
cdef class Tree:
    cdef object key
    cdef Tree left
    cdef Tree right

    cdef PyObject** find(self, key):
        # get the address of self
        # return &self
        # return &(<PyObject*>self)
```

- `&self` fails with `Cannot take address of Python variable`.
- `&(<PyObject*>self)` fails with `Taking address of non-lvalue`, and I'm not sure that `self` is actually a `PyObject*`.

Comment: when you are passing `self` it is already a reference. If you are wrapping a C++ class and you want to delete the C++ class instance [you can follow the common practice suggested here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#create-cython-wrapper-class)

Comment: Hey @SaulloCastro, I'm not wrapping any code, just using Cython, I want to use a pointer to a object, the idea is to have one level of indirection.

Comment: Just to add some context, I'm implementing a Tree in pure cython as an exercise to learn the language, and because I want to implement other data structures. I want to use pointers to simplify the delete code, specially for deleting leaf nodes, the idea is avoid  using a `parent` object, be it a variable passed around or a Node attribute.

Answer (score 2):

`<void*>self` and `<PyObject*>self` works just fine to get a pointer to self.

```py
from ctypes import addressof, c_int
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject
from cython.operator import address
from libc.stdio cimport printf


cdef class A:
   cdef object py
   cdef int c

   def __init__(self, py, c):
        self.py = py
        self.c = c

   cdef void* addrvoid(self):
       return <void*>self

   cdef PyObject* addr(self):
       return <PyObject*>self


cpdef run():
    cdef A a
    a = A([], 1)

    # these are all equivalent
    printf('a=%lu\n', <void*>a)
    printf('a=%lu\n', <PyObject*>a)
    printf('a=%lu\n', a.addrvoid())
    printf('a=%lu\n', a.addr())

    # type casting doesnt work with the extension's c attributes because it
    # will translate to the arrow operator, like: (void *)__pyx_v_a->b)
    # printf('%lu\n', <void*>a.c)
    # printf('%lu\n', <void*>(a.c))
    # printf('%lu\n', <PyObject*>(a.c))

    # and address() dont work with python attributes
    # printf('a.py=%lu\n', <void*>address(a.py))

    # but address works with c attributes
    printf('a.c=%lu\n', address(a.c))

    # and type casting works with python attributes
    printf('a.py=%lu\n', <void*>(a.py))

    # it works with ctypes too
    i = c_int(1)
    print('cint=' + str(id(i)))
    printf('cint=%lu\n', <void*>i)

    # but it evaluates to the address of the python object
    print('cint=' + str(addressof(i)))
```

Running this code will result in something like:

> a=140516369271496
>   a=140516369271496
>   a=140516369271496
>   a=140516369271496
>   a.c=140516369271528
>   a.py=140516452410632
>   cint=140516465032184
>   cint=140516465032184
>   cint=140516465032264